# Bootstrap modal is not taking the button backward

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

My code is working but the button is not going backward after clicking.
 [Here is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM7ym.png)

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Launch Demo Modal</a>
```

Here is the Html code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
            <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#c').click(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

i have created a working fiddle. 
[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkeq1983/1/)
Just add a on click event and hide the modal.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Launch Demo Modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
            <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button id = "test" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  >Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#c').click(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
$("#test").on("click", () =>{
        alert("save changes")
    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but this thing is still not going backward like before... maybe something wrong wit my code happened but i could not figure that out!!